# Generate .WASM module from C#

Tags: c#, .net, webassembly

I just want to generate a .WASM file from C# code. However, both [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor) and [Uno Platform](https://platform.uno/uno-platform-for-web-webassembly/), seem to indicate that you have to create an via their respective application. Is there a way to simply generate the module?

Comment: Your question rests on some fundamental assumptions that are probably invalid.  For starters, no programming language is an island; every programming language operates in an "environment."  The purpose of Blazor and Uno is not just to translate from one language to another; it's to transport you from one environment to another.  That's why all of this pesky infrastructure that Uno and Blazor provides exists.

Comment: So looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Using_the_JavaScript_API, it seems like I should be able to make a `.wasm` file and load it via JS. From there I should be able to invoke functions that were exported. I don't need an entire environment to do this.

Comment: https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap